# python: remove strings found in other files between specific strings

Tags: python, string, find

Ive got a txt file like:

first.txt

> Johnny^plumber^NY;Anna^doctor^Washington;Kate^admin^Florida

then i've got one many output3*.txt files in folder which the data is saving all the time:

> haha plumber blabla;

other one could be like:

> haha doctor blabla;haha admin blabla

if there is no word "exit" in the output3*.txt files - its waiting for few seconds and then searching those words (plumber doctor admin) between haha and blabla in every file which didnt had "exit" inside and removing those words from the first txt file.

```
file_names3 = glob.glob(pathtemp+"/output3*.txt")
abort_after = 1 * 5
start = time.time()
while True:
    if not file_names3:
        break
    delta = time.time() - start
    if delta >= abort_after:
        with open(path+"/"+statuses, "a") as statuses:
            statuses.write("-----------------\n ERRORS:\n\n-----------------\n")
            for file_name in file_names3:
                statuses.write("%s" % file_name + " - file not done: ")
                with open(file_name, 'r') as prenotf:
                    reader=prenotf.read()
                    for "haha" in reader:
                        finding=reader[reader.find("haha")+5:reader.find("blabla")]


                        statuses.write(finding)

        break
    time.sleep(3)
    for file_name in file_names3:
        with open(file_name, "r") as zz:
            if "exit" in zz.read():   #<<<--- test data
                file_names3.remove(file_name)
                print ("\n ############# List of files still Waiting to be done:\n")
                print (file_names3)
```

Im stuck in searching for those words between haha and blabla.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: you're removing items from `file_names3` while iterating in `for file_name in file_names3:`

Comment: Why have you kept a file open even after reading it?

Answer (score 0):

When you alter an object while you're iterating through it, you foul up the inherent location pointer.  This pointer is absolute.  If you delete 10 characters from the file, the rest of the file shifts up, but the pointer doesn't change.  This effective skips the next 10 characters.

Your logic comes in two parts, then:

- Write to a second file while you parse the first.  Once you're done, you can move the new file to the old name.
- Maintain an *active* flag.  Turn it off when you hit **haha** and back on when you hit **blabla**.

It looks something like this:

```
temp_file = open("tempfile.txt", 'w')

active = True
for line in <your input>:
    if "haha" in line:
        active = True
    elif "blabla" in line:
        active = False
    elif active
        temp_file.write(line)
```

Can you work that into your program's current logic?